# Image in React Native Android

Tags: android, bundle, react-native

I have the following line of code in my sample demo app to display a static image from asset folder.It works fine but the image disappears when i load offline bundle(Production apk).

```
  <Image  source={require('./assets/image/sample.png')}  style={{width: 400, height: 450 , padding:10}}/>
```

and my project structure looks like this:-

[image: Image in React Native Asset Folder]

After i tried to bundle the app for offline apk using the below command:-

```
 react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output [path for bundle output] --assets-dest [assets-path for image files]
```

I have the following structure in draw able folder

[image: Generated Image in Android-drawable folder]

The confusion here is why react native changes the image name when bundling in this way.And i am not able to see the image after offline bundle please guide me on this as i have googled enough but not able to understand the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Should not the image source be

```
require('./assets/image/sample.png')
```

instead of

```
require('./assets/sample.png')
```

Comment: thanks i missed the path when copying to stack overflow. But in source file the path is correct.